# Fill in absent elements in an array

Tags: php, arrays, date, time

I have a code that generates total posts from a database per hour for the latest **10 hours**. Now, the problem is that only hours with posts are displayed, but that won't work for me because i want to display the whole thing as a chart.

Example of the current array:

```
    array("12"=>"20403",
          "15"=>"17017",
          "17"=>"84013");
```

The keys represent the hour in a 24 format. So what i need is a function that fills in the empty hours with 0 value.

Example:

```
$currenthour=date('H'); // i think it may be based on the latest hour.

array("11"="0",
      "12"=>"20403",
      "13"=>"0",
      "14"=>"0",
      "15"=>"17017",
      "16"=>"0",
      "17"=>"84013",
      "18"=>"0",
      "19"=>"0",
      "20"=>"0");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach(range(0, 23) as $hour)
   if(!isset($ary[$hour]))
       $ary[$hour] = 0;
ksort($ary);
```

to fill in only last hours you may need something like

```
function last_hours($hour, $cnt) {
    return $hour < $cnt - 1 ?
        array_merge(range($hour, 0), range(23, 25 - $cnt + $hour)) :
        range($hour, $hour - $cnt + 1);
}
```

and then

```
$now = date("G");
$new_array = array();
foreach(last_hours($now, 10) as $hour)
   $new_array[$hour] = isset($ary[$hour]) ? $ary[$hour] : 0;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks but i think this would fill it with 24 hours range, i just need the latest 10 hours

Comment: ...So figure out what the 'range' is for "the latest 10 hours", and that for the loop instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array_fill`](http://php.net/array_fill) **OR** do it with a loop (assuming `$hours` is your array:

```
$currenthour=date('H');
for($i = $currenthour; $i < 23; $i++)
    if(!isset($hours[$i]))
         $hours[$i] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate through the array, and see if the value at the index is set. Like this:

Edit with your the last 10 hours:

```
$currenthour=date('H')

$beginrange = $currenthour - 10
if ($beginrange =< 0)
    $beginrange = 23 + $beginrange
$endrange = $currenthour

//set up the for loop
foreach(range($beginrange, $endrange) as $i)
   //check if the element is set
   if(!isset($array[$i])) 
       // set it
       $array[$i] = 0;
```

Comment: @ David, added your range requirement!

Comment: Thanks, but what if the latest hour was 00:00, then it would be -10?